# includes mess up when importing in android NDK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, adt

Whenever I import a project into the NDK, the local source includes are always fine and import over correctly. However, the other major ones (such as android_native_app_glue.h) are always unresolved when I import the project over. They were not unresolved when I created the project from scratch; however, I am working through the a book on the NDK and would like to know how to import android projects without having to re-create the project and cut/paste the code from the old project from scratch in order to fix the . Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your complaint is probably about the behavior of Eclipse. If this is so, you will be better served if you add the relevant tag(s), e.g. eclipse, adt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click to your project that includes the jni folder, go to project references and click the project that contains the files you want to include.

Make sure you have set the right path in your android.mk file for your external project

You can fix also the path names using LOCAL_C_INCLUDES in your library.
For example: `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../externalProject/src/`
and then supposing that the src folder contains the files externalfile.cpp, externalfile.h you can write in your jni

`#include externalfile.cpp`

In my project though, I have some compiler problems. For example, if I change something in a class of an external file the compiler does not recognize it immediately. So I have to delete the errors and run the application again and then it runs normally. I have also compiler problems with the external project and sometimes I have to delete the errors and start the application again. And then it runs without problems.

Good luck!